# Avoiding new lines in a variable and printing values in a single line

Tags: javascript

```
function trim(grp) 
{ 
    grp = grp.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
    grp = grp.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," "); 
    grp = grp.replace(/\n /,"\n"); 
    return grp;
}
```

Input values:

```
VEC Compute (ICoE)
Enterprise Cloud Connector
CIE (Cloud Infrastructure Engineering)
```

Expected result :

```
VEC Compute (ICoE),Enterprise Cloud Connector,CIE (Cloud Infrastructure Engineering)
```

Comment: What kind of line ending you have? `\r\n`?

Comment: \r\n the inputs will be dynamic as mentioned above inspite of count

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.replace(/(\s*[\r\n]\s*)+/g, ',')`

```js
var value = `   VEC Compute (ICoE) 
  Enterprise Cloud Connector  

   CIE (Cloud Infrastructure Engineering)   `;

function trim(grp) {
    return grp
        .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
        .replace(/(\s*[\r\n]\s*)+/g, ',');
}

console.log(trim(value));
```

Comment: can i use outstr = (joined) ; ?

Comment: OP wants to trim each line as well so `/(?:\s*(?:\r|\n)\s*)+/g`

Comment: @AZ_ Thanks. `/\s*[\r\n]\s*/g` works, and is a bit simpler.

Comment: @DDTesseract Not sure I understand the question. If you want to call it `outstr` instead of `joined`, go right ahead.

Comment: @JLRishe better to make the groups non-capturing if not required.